# Add "from date" and "to date" in GROUP PRICE

Tags: magento-1.7, price, group-price

we have a magento 1.7.0.2 and we use "group price" to set different price for registered user. 
It works fine, but I would like to implement the "from date" and "to date" to automatically enable and disable promotions like special price. 
I don't want to use catalogue rules because i've to menage all single product price.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This question also exists on stackoverflow: "[Adding a From and a To date for tier prices in admin module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14472070/magento-adding-a-from-and-a-to-date-for-tier-prices-in-admin-module)".

The conclusion is "this is not possible by default within, magento" and the solution is creating a custom module which listens to the `sales_quote_add_item` and modifies the price/applied promotions of an item added to the cart, if the current date is not in the specified range.

The question is based on the same version number of Magento (1.7) as you are using.